# How do you implement rate-limit-flexible on all event as a middleware in socket.io node js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to implement rate-limit-flexible middleware on all socket event listener, just like express middleware. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [onAny](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#socketonanylistener) and [prependAny](https://socket.io/docs/v4/listening-to-events/#socketprependanylistener) listeners.